# Formatted a Bootcamped drive as a dynamic disk, now can't boot to either Mac or Windows

Tags: bootcamp, startup, filesystem

I was trying to create an extra partition to get a file from the Windows side of my Macbook Air to the Mac side, and I accidentally made the disk dynamic without realizing it. I am now unable to boot to the Mac side (holding Alt to go into the system manager at startup doesn't even list the Mac partition), and the Windows side blue screens during boot (goes so quickly that it doesn't even get to the error code before restarting).

What can I do to fix the issue? I don't know how to make a bootable flash drive that a Mac will recognize, and Disk Utility (via Internet Recovery) couldn't do anything.

Answer (score 4):

Here's some advice offered to others in situations I believe are markedly similar to yours:

"Saving my Data. Convert Dynamic Disk to Basic NTFS" *[Contains a link to an open source software repair utility]* http://www.allroundgeek.com/2011/05/saving-my-data-convert-dynamic-disk-to.html

"Convert Dynamic disk back to basic" *[Contains links to commercial software repair utilities]*
http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/running-windows-anything-else-your-mac/208489-convert-dynamic-disk-back-basic.html

"How to recover Bootcamp NTFS Partition" *[A multi-page walkthrough of tailormade hex-editing, command-line and open source remedies offered by a knowledgeable (and patient) individual to an ongoing parade of Bootcamp users who unintentionally created dynamic (a/k/a Windows LDM) NTFS drives which will not boot into either Windows or OS X.]*
http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1405449